# taking a static animation and making it move unity3d

Tags: unity, animation

Say you have an animation of a bird flapping its wing.

Some animations actually moves the Avatar either forward, backwards or to the side.

My question is, is it possible to take that flapping animation and change the animation to make it move forward within the unity editor?

Please note that i am not an animator which means that i do not have the skills to edit the animation in a 3rd party program. So this question revolves around what you can do in `Unity3d`

Comment: Wouldn't you want the animation to move "forward" by moving the game object? What you are describing is Root Motion. But this only works if the animation contains the bird moving in the animation itself.